# Why my JQuery doesn't load on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I did this javascript quiz : http://utbm.trunat.fr/CIP/quiz/

It works on normal browser but doesn't even load with Internet Explorer.

It seams that it doesn't recognize the `initQuiz()` function.

Do you have any idea of how I can fix this ?

Comment: Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 113
Char: 460
Code: 0
URI: http://utbm.trunat.fr/CIP/quiz/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 110
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://utbm.trunat.fr/CIP/quiz/js/start-quiz.js

Comment: I love how there are two categories of browsers: normal browsers, and IE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Internet Explorer doesn't accept the trailing comma:

  ```
  question = {'texte': $(this).attr("texte"),
      'sound': $(this).attr("sound"),}
  ```
- Apparently, another error comes from this line:

  ```
  $('title').html(QUIZ_TITLE[lang]);
  ```

  Turns out [you can't set the title like that in IE](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6899). Use `document.title = QUIZ_TITLE[lang]` instead.
- A third error is that you're introducing a new variable, `question` without the `var` keyword, which is an error in IE. You're doing it again, later on, in `response`. Update your `loadXML` as such:

  ```
  function loadXML(xml) {
     $(xml).find("question").each(function() {
      var question = {'texte': $(this).attr("texte"), 'sound': $(this).attr("sound")};

        reponses = [];
        $(this).find('carre').find('reponse').each(function() {
          var reponse = {'texte': $(this).text(), 'sound': $(this).attr("sound"), 'bonne': false};
          if($(this).attr('bonne') == "vrai") reponse['bonne'] = true;            
          reponses.push(reponse);
       });

       question['reponses'] = reponses;
       questions.push(question);
     });
     startGame(questions);
  }
  ```
- A fourth error is in the way you're verifying that an answer is correct.

  ```
  if($(this).attr('data-type') == 'true')
  ```

  You compare the value of the `data-type` attribute to the string value `"true"`, but when you *assign* the value, you set it to the boolean value `true`:

  ```
  $('#r'+(i+1)+'input').attr('data-type', r.bonne);
  ```

  To make sure that you're always comparing string values, for instance, you could set the value as such:

  ```
  $('#r'+(i+1)+'input').attr('data-type', r.bonne.toString());
  ```

Comment: Is it possibly the `$(this).attr('sound')` when sound is not defined that raise an error ?

Comment: That error was in `loadXML(xml)`. It prevented `loadXML`, and possibly other functions, from executing. Until it has been corrected, it is difficult to tell whether or not there are other errors.

Comment: Ah; interesting. I'll have another look at it.

Comment: I fixed other errors that I saw using : http://www.jslint.com/ - But still it doesn't work.

Comment: Alright, see my edit. I believe we've found all the errors now.

Comment: Ok I fixed them and I will try on IE as soon as I come back a Windows PC. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ok I tried it and the quiz works but the answer are always wrong even if it it the good answer ... I don't know why yet but I will look into it. Thank you. Also the swfobject never appear.

Comment: I found out why you always get the wrong answer in the quiz; see my updated answer. I'm not sure I see what you mean with swfobject. The little 'control panel' with the play and pause buttons appear just fine to me.

Comment: Ok, this is just perfect. Thank you for you help really. Let me give pay you a beer :) http://beeroverip.org/